# select previous row of particular event in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2016

I am current working on a problem.. where i need previous event of applaunch in excel

```
 Input 
    notification_dismiss
    notification_dismiss
    notification_dismiss
    AppLaunch
    notification_dismiss
    notification_dismiss
    AppLaunch
    notification_dismiss
    AppLaunch
    notification_dismiss
    notification_dismiss
    AppLaunch


Expected Output
notification_dismiss
AppLaunch
notification_dismiss
AppLaunch
notification_dismiss
AppLaunch
notification_dismiss
AppLaunch
```

Comment: Title of your questions says about selection of rows, but sample output looks like you need to delete rows. What exactly do you need? Also what you've tried to solve it?

Comment: I suspect what you show as text is placeholders for something else that is likely varied, otherwise, you could simply write the output without the input.  It is impossible to provide a solution without knowing what the actual data looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I'm assuming that you have data in Range `A2:A13`.**

**Earlier:**

[image]

**After Records been Filtrated:**

[image]

**How it works:**

1. Write this Formula in Cell `B2` to create one **Helper Column** & fill it Down.

`=IF(A2=A1,COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,A2),1)`

1. Select entire Data Range(`A2:B13`) and apply **Auto Filter**.
2. **Filter** 1s only.

   [image]

*Adjust Cell references in the Formula as needed.*

Comment: Gald to help you @Nrj, keep asking ☺